# how to make parent component enclose children

Tags: svg, reactjs

I'm writing a model viewer with reactjs and svg. I want to make a parent component enclose a group of child components.

The child components are automatically sized according to their label text width. But how should the parent component get access the child sizes in order to calculate the smallest enclosing rect?

The problem seems to be how to communicate information upwards in the component hierarchy.

```
// child automatically sized after text width
var Child = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        var rect = this.refs.rect.getDOMNode();
        var text = this.refs.text.getDOMNode();
        rect.setAttribute('width', text.offsetWidth + 8);
    },
    render: function() {
        return <g transform={'translate(' + this.props.x + ', ' + this.props.y + ')'}>
            <rect ref="rect" height={50} fill="#cfc"/>
            <text ref="text" x={4} y={15}>{this.props.text}</text>
        </g>;
    }
});

// parent that I want to automatically enclose all children
var Parent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <g>
            <rect x={10} y={10} width={200} height={100} fill="#ccf"/>
            <Child text="first child" x={20} y={20}/>
            <Child text="second child" x={180} y={80}/>
          </g>;
    }
});

var Diagram = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <svg width={300} height={250}><Parent/></svg>;
    }
});

React.render(<Diagram/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Try the code here https://jsfiddle.net/dagrende/ep6xrLqy/1/.

Comment: Have you tried an event (when the width is calculated, raise an event to the `Parent`)?

Comment: To communicate upwards: callbacks. Call a callback giving their width values to the parent and keep a list of width. That way you always know the values of the width when they change.

Comment: @JeremyD: a callback worked! But where is the best place to store the list? To me it doesn't seem to be part of state or props, but I'm new to react.

Comment: The parent needs to know about those widths right? So I would store in the the state of a parent. Should I create an answer?

Comment: @JeremyD An answer with a jsfiddle would be best, if you have time.